# How do I change username 'root' in phpMyAdmin with WAMP?

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I've just installed WAMP on a new device and I forget how to change the username in phpMyAdmin as the default is currently 'root' I would like to change it to 'lamp'. I already know how to change the password just can't remember the username.

Comment: I think if you go to the mysql's installation path (not sure if there, look around for it )  there was a configuration wizard, from wich you could do that. Or maybe just reinstall wamp, and remember to set the username. Anyway, it's recommended to have a root account with full access, and set up another account the specific permissions.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer have you installed? It makes a difference.

Comment: Wampserver (64 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4

Answer (score 3):

OK if you want to change the Super User from `root` to `lamp` can I suggest your create a new Super User called `lamp`, test it, make sure it does as you expect. And then and only then you can delete the old Super User `root`.

As the phpMyAdmin that comes with WAMPServer 2.4 now throws a login page for userid and password entry rather than storing it in the config file its just like creating any other userid to create `lamp` just remember to allocate Global Privilages to all 3 of them.

All 3 of them being one for each of the standard domains, 127.0.0.1 and localhost and ::1

EDIT: Answer to comment

How to rename a user from the MySQL Console:

```
RENAME USER 'root'@'localhost' TO 'lamp'@'localhost';
RENAME USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' TO 'lamp'@'127.0.0.1';
RENAME USER 'root'@'::1' TO 'lamp'@'::1';
```

Comment: would you happen to know what I put in the MySQL console command to do that?

Comment: No, but I can find out fairly quickly. See additional info on answer.